# Проблема при создании связи один к одному

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Добрый день!

У меня есть два класса:

```
class OfficeModel: Object {

   var id = RealmOptional<Int>()
   @objc dynamic var city: String?
   @objc dynamic var address: String?
   @objc dynamic var phone: String?

   @objc dynamic var coordinate: OfficeСoordinates?

  convenience init(json: JSON) {
    self.init()
    self.id.value = json["Id"].int
    self.city = json["City"].string
    self.address = json["Address"].string
    self.coordinate = OfficeСoordinates(json: json["Coordinates"])
  }
}

class OfficeСoordinates: Object {

  var latitude = RealmOptional<Double>()
  var longitude = RealmOptional<Double>()

  convenience init(json: JSON) {
    self.init()

    self.latitude.value = json["Latitude"].double
    self.longitude.value = json["Longitude"].double
  }
}
```

При запуске, при первом обращении к realm происходит ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=1 "Schema validation failed due to the following errors:
>   Property 'OfficeModel.coordinate' of type 'object' has unknown object type 'OfficeСoordinates'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Schema validation failed due to the following errors:
>   Property 'OfficeModel.coordinate' of type 'object' has unknown object type 'OfficeСoordinates', Error Code=1}: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.74.1/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 181
>   2017-12-21 13:19:05.559834+0500 EnergoIndividual[73534:5337172] Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=1 "Schema validation failed due to the following errors:
>   Property 'OfficeModel.coordinate' of type 'object' has unknown object type 'OfficeСoordinates'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Schema validation failed due to the following errors:
>   Property 'OfficeModel.coordinate' of type 'object' has unknown object type 'OfficeСoordinates', Error Code=1}: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.74.1/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 181

Объявление свойства @objc dynamic var coordinate: OfficeСoordinates? происходит по официальной [документации](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#using-the-realm-framework)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем здесь проблема?

Realm framework version: 3.0.2

Realm Object Server version: n/a

Xcode version: 9.1

iOS/OSX version: iOS11

Dependency manager + version: Cocoapods 1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Если вы меняете объекты БД, то после изменения нужно сделать миграцию данных. Например так:

```
    public func migrateDB(toVersion version: UInt64) {
    let config = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: version,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if oldSchemaVersion < version {
                //тут делается миграция вручную по отдельным полям
                //если вы, к примеру, изменили primaryKey объекта
            }
    })
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
    let _ = try! Realm()
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за идею, но это новое приложение с нуля и я удалял приложения на эмуляторе и запускал сново, но проблема та же.